# Use multiple Analyzers on same field - Apache Lucene

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, lucene

I'm using apache lucene 6.3.0 and I want to index my field 'file_name' using 2 Analyzers:
1. StandardAnalyzer (to allow search using terms)
2. KeywordAnalyzer (to preserve the original name also, just in case if the user searches the entire name)

Please note that this can be achieved using search time input analysis but I want to avoid adding that complexity on the search front of my app.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, so you'll either have to:

- Have two fields with different processing and use `copyField` to index the same content into both fields, but process it differently (this is useful to also score exact hits higher than those that has been processed by the StandardTokenizer)
- Use the KeywordTokenizer [together with a `WordDelimiter(Graph)Filter`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterGraphFilter) and set `preserveOriginal` to true.

The first will allow you to prioritize fields differently, but will require you to include both fields when querying. The latter will have all the data in a single field, but won't allow you to score them differently.